# Pico power supply

Tags: power-supply

I just bought a [Pico power supply](http://www.mini-box.com/s.nl/it.A/id.417/.f) to power my mother board.  But I am unsure what kind of adapter I need that will plug into the wall.  I would like to find a cheaper alternative then the ones listed on their site.  The 8.5A adapter is selling for $35.  I see plenty of 19V ones on ebay that sell for cheap.  But the pico power supply needs a 12V input source.  Would the power supply be able to reduce to 19V to only 12V to the motherboard?

Would something like this work?
[Ebay link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-12V-72W-AC-POWER-SUPPLY-ADAPTER-FOR-LCD-MONITOR-6A-/290464529014?pt=Laptop_Adapters_Chargers&hash=item43a108fa76)

Comment: 19V will probably kill your power supply.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote was probably due to the fact that this is not really an electronics design problem, more a item specific "technical support" question. To answer the question though: if it says it needs 12V, then 19V won't do - use 12V.

Comment: See this Q&A about power supplies: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Answer (score 4):

The [manual](http://resources.mini-box.com/online/PWR-PICOPSU-120/PWR-PICOPSU-120-manual-engl.pdf) says:

> **Input Requirements:** 12V regulated, min=2A, max=10A (load
>   dependent). Over-voltage shutdown will occur at ~13-13.5V.

So 19 V may not kill it, but if not will shut the power supply down. Use a 12 V regulated input as required.